# i can not create a table in kafka ksql

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb

this is my sql,i don't know what's wrong

```
CREATE TABLE memo_src (
    'id' VARCHAR PRIMARY KEY,
    'title' VARCHAR,
    'cover_image' VARCHAR
  ) WITH (
    KAFKA_TOPIC = 'memo.memorandum.memorandum_info',
    VALUE_FORMAT='AVRO'
);
```

Then prompt me as follows

```
extraneous input ''id'' expecting {'EMIT', 'CHANGES', 'INTEGER', 'DATE', 'TIME', 'TIMESTAMP', 'INTERVAL', 'YEAR', 'MONTH', 'DAY', 'HOUR', 'MINUTE', 'SECOND', 'ZONE', 'PARTITION', 'STRUCT', 'EXPLAIN', 'ANALYZE', 'TYPE', 'TYPES', 'SHOW', 'TABLES', 'COLUMNS', 'COLUMN', 'PARTITIONS', 'FUNCTIONS', 'FUNCTION', 'ARRAY', 'MAP', 'SET', 'RESET', 'SESSION', 'KEY', 'SINK', 'SOURCE', 'IF', IDENTIFIER, DIGIT_IDENTIFIER, QUOTED_IDENTIFIER, BACKQUOTED_IDENTIFIER}
Statement: CREATE TABLE memo_src (
    'id' VARCHAR PRIMARY KEY,
    'title' VARCHAR,
    'cover_image' VARCHAR
  ) WITH (
    KAFKA_TOPIC = 'memo.memorandum.memorandum_info',
    VALUE_FORMAT='AVRO'
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your id, title and cover_image are not supposed to be in quotation marks. That's why the compiler states it did not expect the token 'id'.